# Swift 3 draw a simple png image with transparency

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, png, core-graphics

I need to draw no more than 9 of the same image around an arc. I subclassed UiView already to draw a circle and several arcs with CoreGraphics. Now i need to draw these marker objects around it like a clock. I have already done this once in Android Java but have been having a hell of a time so far in Swift. 
I cobbled together this code from another answer and it draws the image but doesnt keep the transparency:

```
let imageName = "single_marker_vertical_high_res.png";
let image = UIImage(named: imageName);
let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!);
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 25, height: 75);
imageView.draw(rect)
```

and this is called on the overridden draw function of the class.
I am a noob when it comes to Swift as well, I have yet to find an example that shows the code and how to utilize it. For reference, this is what I need:
[As it looks on Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V96iv.png) 
The tick marks on the top widget is what I need to draw, with transparency.

Comment: One wouldn’t generally call `draw` an image view. You just add it to the view hierarchy and the OS will render it for you. (Also, you don’t need all of those semicolons.) Re your problem, check `isOpaque` property of the imageview.

Comment: Thanks, between you and Duncan I think I got it working. And I am aware that I do not need the semicolons but at this point I am switching between Swift, Java, and JavaScript on what is sometimes an hourly basis and since they do not harm the program, its easier for me to just stay consistant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never call drawRect directly. Place image views at the desired locations, install your images, and the system will draw them for you. Set the image view's opaque flags to false.

You should probably place the image views using AutoLayout constraints rather than placing them using frames. The system will move them around if you don't add constraints. Take a look at `NSLayoutAnchor`. It's an easy way to create constraints.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write xml explicitly, while you can write code for custom & reusable views, but a better approach is to use storyboard, it takes care of the constraints, which are relatively very easy to handle. After adding your wanted object in storyboard. e.g you want to add a circle, you can drag the view, place it wherever you want and then make it a circle with properties like `view.layer.cornerRadius =` half of your height, you can also hide/show via properties like isHidden, opaque and do a bunch of stuff. if you need any help just ask.